# Algorithm to produce metrics for a GPS track

Tags: general-topology

Forewarning: my background is software development, not maths so please KISS...

For a given GPS track (a series of xyz coordinates) I'd like to devise an algorithm to score the track based on the 'tightness' of the curves. i.e. a track with a number of tight turns should have an index greater than one with longer, shallower turns.

How would you go about this?

Comment: @WillJagy No, no, no, software development doesn't work that way.  :-)  Anyway, [curvature of space curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_space_curves) could be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome to your world: it's appreciated. I shan't to respond to your bait with any background, instead I'll let you continue to live out your cynical fantasy that I'll use this new found knowledge to make millions of dollars from building a "killer app", then blow all the proceeds on drugs and hookers whilst the true heroes, the mathematicians, go unnoticed. Oh, then I'll sell the movie rights. Software development: it's just like rock and roll. WillJagy - do you not think comments like this go against the mission of SE? @WimC - thanks for the help, it's appreciated.

Comment: Huh, what happened here? I don't see anything in the OP that is ungrateful or impolite... just looks to me like a software developer needing some geometry guidance...